# How to refer library dependencies for android project using ant

Tags: java, android, ant

I'm developing an app for Google map from command line using ANT. How can I import the Google play services library to my project using Ant. I tried updating the project using this command:

`./android update project --target 2 --path Googlemaps --library  /home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/`

But when I clean the project it gives 'Build Failed' Error. Have I missed anything else.
  This is My Project.properties file

```
 target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:19
 android.library.reference.1=/home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/
```

I get error when I clean project

```
Buildfile: /home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/Googlemaps/build.xml

 -check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-linux

 -setup:
 [echo] Project Name: Googlemaps
 [gettype] Project Type: Application

 -pre-clean:

  clean:

  BUILD FAILED
   /home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:460:          
  /home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ resolve to a    
  path with no project.properties file for project /home/shvetajeevan/Downloads/android-sdk-l   inux/tools/Googlemaps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Play Services library is not set up for Ant builds, this will not directly work.

First, you should copy the Play Services library someplace outside of your Android SDK. Then, run **`android update project`** from the library project's main directory to create its own `build.xml` and `project.properties` files.

That should allow you to build projects that depend upon this library project.

Comment: can I copy the play services library to my project? and refer to that path

Comment: @user3620233: Since the Play Service library project will be updated from time to time, you need to keep it sufficiently separate from your own project code that you can take on the updates efficiently. I suppose you can put it in a subdirectory within your project directory -- while I don't do it that way, I cannot think of a reason off the top of my head why it would not work.

Comment: how to create build.xml file keeping the play services library folder outside the sdk folder because to create build.xml we can't create path outside sdk..

Comment: @user3620233: I have no idea what you are talking about. You may wish to read [the documentation on setting up Android library projects for command-line builds](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html). Or, consider switching to Gradle for Android, as Ant support is being deprecated, and adding in Play Services to a Gradle for Android build takes about two lines in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: sorry for not conveying it properly my problem is "First, you should copy the Play Services library someplace outside of your Android SDK. Then, run android update project from the library project's main directory to create its own build.xml". can you clarify this step more precisely..

Comment: @user3620233: The Android SDK consists of files and sub-directories in a directory. One such sub-directory is `extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`. Copy that somewhere else on your hard drive, away from where your Android SDK is installed, so that when Google updates the Android SDK, your copy is not immediately altered. Then, from the command line, switch into your copy of `extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` and run **`android update project -p .`**.

Comment: it does not get any error when I build now, but i do keep getting runtime exception and the app crashes still it is missing something. Can u plz help..